# Outlook VSTO - ActiveInspector returns the incorrect contact window's information

Tags: outlook, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-addins

```
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers.NewExplorer += new ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler(DoNewExplorer);
```

I am trying to get the information from an email that I previously opened (by double-clicking) in outlook.
The code works fine until I open multiple emails. What I am finding is that when I click on an email, the inspector activates, but I am getting the information from the last active window, not the current one that I clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) event handler you can always call the [ActiveInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeinspector) method of the Outlook `Application` class.

Note, the [Inspectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.inspectors) collection contains all opened inspector windows, so you could get all of them or find the required one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code tracks the `Explorers.NewExplorer` event, not `Inspectors.NewInspector`.

Secondly, for the `Inspectors.NewInspector` event, make sure you are using the `Inspector` object passed to your event handler rather than `Application.ActiveInspector`: by the time `Inspectors.NewInspector` event fires, the inspector might not yet be visible/active.

Comment: I am using this code                                        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers.NewExplorer += new ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler(DoNewExplorer);
                _wrappedInspectors = new Dictionary<Guid, InspectorWrapper>();
                _inspectors = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors;
                _inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(DoNewInspector);

Comment: Can we add filter For contact inspector window , because it working fine for my mail items

Comment: Please reply me

Comment: Sure, just check what the value of the `Inspector.CurrentItem.Class` property is (where `Inspector` is passed to your event handler).